# Rails 3 TimeZone Problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, timezone

I have a Problem in my Rails application.

I've left everything at standard Rails configuration, so no config.time_zone is set, ...

Problem now is:
Given I have a database entry like this:

```
 c = Client.first
 => #<Client id: 1, short: "Test", last_connected_at: "2011-06-21 09:22:58">
```

now I generate a Time-Object:

```
t = Time.zone.parse("2011-06-21 09:22:58")
```

double check it:

```
c.last_connected_at
=> Tue, 21 Jun 2011 09:22:58 UTC +00:00
t
=> Tue, 21 Jun 2011 09:22:58 UTC +00:00
```

So it is identical, but

```
c.last_connected_at == t => false
```

Why??? That makes it really hard to find a database row by date.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a caveat. According to the [ruby-docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000343):

> All times may have fraction. Be aware of this fact when
>   comparing times with each other—times that are apparently equal
>   when displayed may be different when compared.

`c.last_connected_at.to_i == t.to_i` should work.

Comment: Well, that works in Ruby comparison. But now I want to do a find, like this: Client.where(["last_connected_at = ?", t"]) which doesn't work. I get no results back.